# Customer-supplied encryption keys with dart/gcloud

Tags: encryption, dart, google-cloud-storage

Using [dart-lang/gcloud](https://github.com/dart-lang/gcloud) to read and write files to Google Cloud Storage, is it possible to provide customer-supplied encryption keys?

The Dart gcloud library is built upon [dart-lang/googleapis](https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis) which itself is interfaces with the Cloud Storage REST API, but the HTTP client it uses is so abstracted that it's hard to tell how to set the headers necessary for custom encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no support for custom encryption keys in [package:gcloud](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/gcloud).

Though the [Storage constructor](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/gcloud/0.4.0/gcloud.storage/Storage/Storage.html) accepts an **http.Client**. So you can supply your own client which adds the headers, something along the lines of:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:gcloud/storage.dart' as storage;

class ClientWithKeys extends http.client {
  final String encryptionAlgorithm;
  final String encryptionKey;
  final String encryptionSHA256;

  ClientWithKeys(this.encriptionAlgorithm,
                 this.encriptionKey,
                 this.encryptionSHA256);

  Future<StreamedResponse> send(request) {
    request.headers['x-goog-encryption-algorithm'] = encryptionAlgorithm;
    request.headers['x-goog-encryption-key'] = encryptionKey;
    request.headers['x-goog-encryption-key-sha256'] = encryptionSHA256;
    return super.send(request);
  }
}

code() {
  final client = new ClientWithKeys('<algo>', '<key>', '<sha256>');
  final api = new storage.Storage(client, '<project-id>');
  ...
  client.close();
}
```